# Form submission angular post is not working

Tags: javascript, angular

I am a backend developer, trying to work on angular 
I am trying to open a popup(window.open) with a form submit to an external application from angular. 
"window.open" its submitting request but not the form.
This popup is a common popup (existing application) from other applications. those are existing applications.

**Html**In the HTML page set the form as hidden.

```
    <header>
...
    <ul>
    <li>
       <a href="#" (click)="contactSupportPopUP()">Contact Support</a>
    </li>
....
</ul>
...
    <form [formGroup]="contactSupportForm" action="url" method="post" traget="openSupportPopup">
       <input type="hidden" formControlName="appId" id="appId" value="App1">
       <input type="hidden" formControlName="appNm" id="appNm" value="AppOne">
    ....
    ....
    </form>
</header>
```

**Component.ts**

```
    supportForm: FormGroup; externalAppUrl:string="http://....";
    constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder...)// added formBuilder, formsModule, ReactiveFormModules
    {
     this.supportForm= new FormGroup({
          appId: new FormControl('App1'),
          appNm: new FormControl('AppOne'),
          .....
    }
    public contactSupportPopUP(){
          window.open(this.externalAppUrl);//This open not submitting form
          window.open(this.externalAppUrl+'?appId=App1'&appNm=AppOne&...);//This is working. Dont want tosubmit data in url param.

    }
```

I am not sure how to submit a form to an external app.

one of the existing application has hidden form in JSP, they are able to submit javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to open url in your existing application, you can use an `iframe`.
And, to post form data you use `this.supportForm.value` as `postData` in http post request through angular.